# Otherwise ok running code won't run under systemd

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, systemd, debian-stretch

Another newbie question from my side:)
I tried to look it up but I couldn't find anything that makes sense in this case. 
I have this code which is working fine under normal circumstances.

```
import automationhat
import bluetooth
import time
import sys
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token='56915444444:AAEzP5jy-pMD3ZME0twxY5bXkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd_U')


# Import Adafruit IO MQTT client.
from Adafruit_IO import MQTTClient


ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY      = '73c755488accccccc361a506f700000002ba'
ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = 'flxxxxxxxx'


def connected(client):
    print('Connected to Adafruit IO!  Listening for LockReg changes...')
    # Subscribe to changes on a feed named LockReg.
    client.subscribe('LockReg')

def disconnected(client):
    print('Disconnected from Adafruit IO!')
    sys.exit(1)

def message(client, feed_id, payload, retain):
    print('Feed {0} received new value: {1}'.format(feed_id, payload))

client = MQTTClient(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)

# Setup the callback functions defined above.
client.on_connect    = connected
client.on_disconnect = disconnected
client.on_message    = message

PHONES = ['B0:xx:2D:x0:C9:xx', 'xx:8D:08:xx:C3:7C', 'xx:AB:37:EA:93:xx']

while True:

        print "Checking " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())

        for device in PHONES:
                result = bluetooth.lookup_name(device, timeout=5)
                if (result != None):
                    # Connect to the Adafruit IO server.
            client.connect()
            print('Door unlocked. Nearby: %s (%s)' % (result, device))
                        client.publish('lock.reg', result)
                        automationhat.relay.one.on()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        automationhat.relay.one.off()
            bot.sendMessage(-26934xxxxx, result)
                        time.sleep(180)
                else:
                        print "User out of range"
                        print('Door locked: No Bluetooth device detected. ' )
        time.sleep(10)
```

My systemd lock.service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
 Description=My Lock  Service
 After=multi-user.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/lockreg.py > /home/pi/lock.log 2>&1

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But if executed from systemd on initial boot i get the following error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status lock.service
● lock.service - My Lock  Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lock.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-06-16 18:33:32 CEST; 29min ago
  Process: 492 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/lockreg.py > /home/pi/lock.log 2>&1 (
 Main PID: 492 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 16 18:33:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My Lock  Service.
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi python[492]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi python[492]:   File "/home/pi/lockreg.py", line 11, in <mod
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi python[492]:     import telegram
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi python[492]: ImportError: No module named telegram
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lock.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lock.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 16 18:33:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lock.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Somehow the Telegram module is not accessible when executed from systemd. Why?

thanks for some hints
P.

Comment: you have `telegram` installed global or in `virtualenv` ?

Comment: make sure you use same python interpreter in both cases.

Comment: @zimdero globally as I never installed virtualenv. How could I check?

Comment: @gonczor Not sure how I could set different interpreters...

Comment: can you run `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/lockreg.py` from command line, will it work ?

Comment: @ zimdero Yes it runs no problem...

Comment: @Paolo can you show systemd config for this script? And print how you start it manually?

Comment: to run it manually: python lockreg.py

Comment: I edited my question and included the lock.service file @gonczor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possible things that could be wrong.

It could be that `telegram` is only installed for the user `pi` instead of globally for all users. Check `/home/pi/.local/` to see if you can find telegram there.

If not, you would expect the module to be installed in your system-wide `site-packages` directory. Use the following to find that:

```
> python
Python 2.7.15 (default, May 11 2018, 15:54:10) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> [p for p in sys.path if p.endswith('site-packages')]
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

(It will probably be a different directory foy you, since my `python` lives in `/usr/local/bin`.)

Then check that `telegram` is installed as a file or sub-directory in the `site-packages` directory.

It could also be a permissions issue. Systemd is running your program as a certain user id. Check that the `site-packages` directory and the `telegram` subdirectory are readable by that specific user.

**Edit:** `Systemd` can run in two modes; *system* and *user*. Only the latter runs as a specific user. I would guess that the *system* mode runs as `root`. From the location of your `lock.service` file, I gather you are using systemd in *system* mode. According to your comments, telegram is *only* installed for the user `pi`. So `python` running as `root` *should not see it*, which is exactly what you experience.

So basically you have two choices:

- Install `telegram`  for all users. (Run the install as `root`.)
- Run a user-mode systemd as the user `pi`.

Comment: I checked where Telegram is installed: ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telegram

Comment: ls -l site-packages    drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi   4096 Jun 15 09:01 telegram

Comment: ls -l python2.7   drwx------ 74 pi pi 4096 Jun 15 09:01 site-packages @Roland Smith

Comment: I'm assuming systemd runs the program as the logged in user (pi). To me permissions look ok. Right?

Comment: Installing as root did the job. Thank you!